# getting json with fetch and ajax yields different responses

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

I have been using ajax to get back some json data and recently tried using the [fetch](https://github.com/github/fetch/) implementation. 
I am having different responses, my ajax returns a string with all my *key/value* pairs, while the fetch query is returning response objects which do not at all contain any of my *key/value* pairs. (I am requesting the exact same resource in both examples and receiving different responses)

Could anyone let me know what Im doing wrong or why this is happening?

***ajax request:***

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/" + name + ".json",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        var json = $.parseJSON(data);
        var itemArray = [];
        $.each(json, function() {
                itemArray.push( { value: this.id, label: this.name } );
        });
        //Populate the List
        populateListBox(name, itemArray);
    }
});
```

***console log result: (this is the response I want to be getting using the fetch method)***

> [{"id":1,"name":"two on two","abbreviation":"2v2","inhouse":true,"length":50,"capacity":1,"price":"50.2","salary":"15.22","url":"http://localhost:3000/en/products/1.json"},{"id":2,"name":"threesome Lessons","abbreviation":"3SUM","inhouse":false,"length":50,"capacity":3,"price":"33.33","salary":"11.11","url":"http://localhost:3000/en/products/2.json"},{"id":3,"name":"Prod1","abbreviation":"PRR1","inhouse":true,"length":22,"capacity":2,"price":"20.0","salary":"20.0","url":"http://localhost:3000/en/products/3.json"}]

***fetch request:***

```
fetch("/" + name + ".json")
    .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        return response.json()
    }).then(function(json) {
        var itemArray = populateItemArray(this, json);
        populateListBox(name, itemArray);
    }).catch(function(ex) {
        console.log('parsing failed', ex)
    });
```

***console log result: (Response an object full of other objects but seems to be only an html response without any of my requested data)***

> Response {}
>   body: (...)
>   bodyUsed: false
>   headers: Headers
>   ok: true
>   status: 200
>   statusText: "OK"
>   type: "basic"
>   url: "http://localhost:3000/login?locale=en"
>   **proto**: Response

I am also receiving an error in the console using the fetch method which states the following: **

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

**

Hope someone can assist. :)

**UPDATE:** After closely inspecting my headers in both requests I noticed the following: My AJAX request sends through a CSRF token, as well as a cookie in the header. 
All fetch requests are made as anonymous and unauthenticated (by default)

All that was needed was to add an option to the fetch request as follows:

```
fetch("/" + name + ".json", **{ credentials: 'same-origin' }**)
        .then(function(response) {
            return response.json()
        }).then(function(json) {
            var itemArray = populateItemArray(json);
            itemArray = sortByLabel(itemArray, 'label');
            populateListBox(name, itemArray);
        }).catch(function(ex) {
            console.log('parsing failed', ex)
        });
```

Problem is solved! Took me long enough - the CSRF token is not needed but the cookie is definitely required as that is what allows the request to be an authenticated one. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fetch requires a parameter to make its requests authenticated:

> credentials: 'same-origin'

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, maybe change dataType: "text" to "json"?

Comment: to make things clear, I want the response to be the one I am getting back in the ajax example, but I want that same response using my fetch query. Thank you for your answer. :)